# Is this image too complex for a shallow NN classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to classify a series of images like this one, with each class of comprising images taken from similar cellular structure:

[image]

I've built a simple network in Keras to do this, structured as:

```
1000 - 10
```

The network unaltered achieves very high (>90%) accuracy on MNIST classification, but almost never higher than 5% on these types of images. Is this because they are too complex? My next approach would be to try stacked deep autoencoders.

Comment: Can you provide images of different classes? It all depends on the separation between them.

Comment: I am working on a similar problem where I'm trying to discriminate subtle organic textures on membranes.  I only got good results after serious preprocessing and an ensemble of 10-12 layer networks with convolution layers.
What is the size of your data set and the class proportions?

Comment: @MaCaKi only 1000 images, about 48 in each of 20 classes

Comment: That is incredibly small, if not infeasible for a training a conv nn on the raw images.  It looks like slides of different tissues?   Are they all the same color and size ? You can expand your data set by subsampling and making random rotations if your images are large enough.

Answer (score 0):

First question, is if you run the training longer do you get better accuracy? You may not have trained long enough.

Also, what is the accuracy on training data and what is the accuracy on testing data? If they are both high, you can run longer or use a more complex model. If training accuracy is better than testing accuracy, you are essentially at the limits of your data. (i.e. brute force scaling of model size wont help, but clever improvements might, i.e. try convolutional nets)

Finally, complex and noisy data you may need a lot of data to make a reasonable classification. So you need many, many images.

Deep stacked autoencoders, as I understand it is an unsupervised method, which isn't directly suitable for classification.

Comment: I only have about 1000 images, so I trained with all of them. Neither of the accuracies are high. Check out this page to see how I was intending to try classification with AEs: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Stacked_Autoencoders#Training

Answer (score 0):

Seriously - I don't expect any nonconvolutional model to work well on this type of data.

1. A nonconv net for MNIST works well because the data is well preprocessed (it is centered in the middle and resized to certain size). Your images are not.
2. You may notice (on your pictures) that certain motifs reoccure - like this darker dots - with different positions and sizes - if you don't use convolutional model you will not capture that efficiently (e.g. you will have to recognize a dark dot moved a little bit in the image as a completely different object).

Because of this I think that you should try convolutional MNIST model instead classic one or simply try to design your own.